# How to set the data type of a session variable in Mule?

Tags: mule, session-variables, mule-studio, mule-component

I need to declare the data type of a session variable as integer but couldn't do it. When i tried declaring the session variable as "123", the data type assigned was string. When I tried using MEL ( #[123] ) , the data type assigned was double.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
#[new java.lang.Integer("123")]
```

You need to explicitly define it as an Integer.

Comment: The data type is defined as string if i use the above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why #[123] is Double, because it should default to Integer. #[123.0] does default to Double. But, #[new java.lang.Integer("123")] does work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can  fetch the string value and convert it to Integer

```
#[Integer.parseInt(sessionVars.myInteger)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value 123 into the variabile and get the value transformed using the follwing expression:

## [Integer.parseInt(sessionVars.myInteger)]

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the value as Integer using:

```
<set-session-variable variableName="testVar" value="#[23456]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
```

or

```
 <set-session-variable variableName="testVar" value="#[new java.lang.Integer(23456)]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
```

Here I am getting as Integer :-
[image]